# How to get time of day for each element in a datetime64 array?

Tags: datetime, numpy

In Numpy, I am trying to get the time of day for each element in an array of `datatime64`.

I could settle for a new array of `timedelta64` which contains the time passed since the beginning of day for each element.

I already tried using `numpy.datetime_as_string`, but I don't know how to manipulate the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def datetime64_to_time_of_day(datetime64_array):
    """
    Return a new array. For every element in datetime64_array return the time of day (since midnight).
    >>> datetime64_to_time_of_day(np.array(['2012-01-02T01:01:01.001Z'],dtype='datetime64[ms]'))
    array([3661001], dtype='timedelta64[ms]')
    >>> datetime64_to_time_of_day(np.datetime64('2012-01-02T01:01:01.001Z','[ms]'))
    numpy.timedelta64(3661001,'ms')
    """
    day = datetime64_array.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(datetime64_array.dtype)
    time_of_day = datetime64_array - day
    return time_of_day
```

Comment: Great solution! Can it be adapted to handle non-UTC datetimes?

Answer (score 0):

If using pandas, you can call `pandas.Series.dt.time` to get `datetime.time` objects.